# iphone : Tabbar method not call during compilation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I want an activity indicator on a particular tab bar. I have applied the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol on the `.h` file.

I wrote this method for selecting particular tabbar,

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

this method is not called during compilation. What should I do?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. “method not called during compilation”: did you mean during execution? And what does “applied the protocol in the .h file” mean? Where is this method? Try to make a *short* but complete program that shows the problem and add that complete code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to write

```
   tab.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I have tried your option but it not calling (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item

Comment: urtabbarcontroller.delegate=self;

Answer (score 0):

Have you also did your IBOutlet connection to the tab bar?